# How to optimize group by in table with huge number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Person table with huge number of records(for about 16 million), and have a requirement to find all persons, with same `lastname`, first letter of `firstname` and `birthyear`, in other worlds I want to show assuming duplicate persons in UI for users to analyze and decide are there a same person or not.

Here is the query I write

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(firstName, 1, 1) firstNameF,lastName,YEAR(birthDate) birthYear
    FROM Person
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(firstName, 1,1),lastName,YEAR(birthDate)
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) as dupPersons 
ON SUBSTRING(Person.firstName,1,1) = dupPersons.firstNameF and Person.lastName = dupPersons.lastName and YEAR(Person.birthDate) = dupPersons.birthYear
order by Person.lastName,Person.firstName
```

but as I am not SQL expert, want too know, is this good way to do that? are there more optimized way?

**EDIT**

Note that I can cut data, which can have contribution in optimization

for example if I want to cut data by 2 it could return two persons

```
Johan Smith |
Jane Smith  | have same lastname and first name inita 
Jack Smith  |

Mark Tween  | have same lastname and first name inita 
Mac Tween   |
```

Comment: being born in the same year doesn't narrow it down much, nor does it make it likely 2 people are the same simply because born in same year, have same surname and first initial.  John Smith 1/2/1970,  James Smith 5/7/1970

Comment: I would disagree with @Mitch as to the utility of this set of constraints to identify potential duplicates. I did some work on a database which consisted of ~55 million records - the then population of the UK - and this type of search does usually bring it down to 10s of candidates. Of course an even better filter is using the full date of birth.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I know,just this is one of requirements... so that is not a case

Comment: @Chris Walton: I was alluding to simply using the full date of birth. I'm thinking in terms of performance. I would probably do it differently.

Comment: I have some radiobuttons, where user selects how to search dups, and this is one of methods... I guess more complex and slow performance...

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - are you still working on this issue?  How goes?

Comment: Yea Matt, I will continue to work on this issue after finishing my current task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the performance using a `GROUP BY` is not adequate, You could try using an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Person p1
        INNER JOIN Person p2 ON p2.PersonID > p1.PersonID
WHERE   SUBSTRING(p2.Firstname, 1, 1) = SUBSTRING(p1.Firstname, 1, 1) 
        AND p2.LastName = p1.LastName
        AND YEAR(p2.BirthDate) = YEAR(p1.BirthDate)
ORDER BY
        p1.LastName, p1.FirstName
```

Comment: It works great, after removing sorting it works more faster, but I need to cut first 20 duplicate records, so in this case I can loss records, isn't it?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - I don't follow. Do you need the first 20 records returned or something else?

Comment: I want to find first 20 persons having duplicates, records count can be more than 20, but different persons should be 20

Comment: I assume you don't mean simply adding a `TOP 20` to the `SELECT` but I still have no idea what you DO mean. Perhaps you should post some test data with the results you expect for those hardheads like me to understand.

Comment: I edited my post @Lieven, I guess now it is more understandable with my poor english :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get what you mean by cutting the data. Do you mean fysically separating the data in two different tables?

Comment: Yes @Lieven, I need to do paging

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're not an expert, the query you wrote says to me that you're *at least* pretty competent.  When we look at whether a query is "optimized", there are two immediate parts to that:  1. The query just on its own has something notably wrong with it - a bad join, keyword misuse, exploding result set size, supersitions about `NOT IN`, etc.  2. The context that the query operates within - DB specifics, task specifics, etc.

Your query passes #1, no problem.  I would have written it differently - aliased the Person table, used `LEFT(P.FirstName, 1)` instead of `SUBSTRING`, and used a CTE (`WITH`-clause) instead of a subquery.  But these aren't optimization issues.  Maybe I'd use `WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)` if the results weren't sensitive to dirty reads.  Out of any further context, your query doesn't look like a bomb waiting to go off.

As for #2 - You should probably switch to specifics.  Like "I have to run this every week.  It takes 17 minutes.  How can I get it down to under a minute?"  Then people will ask you what your plan looks like, what indexes you have, etc.

Things I'd want to know:

- How long does it already take to run?
- What's your runtime window?  (User & app tolerance for query time.)
- Is this run once a day?  Week?  Month?  Quarter?
- Do you have the permission to create tables, change current tables, or alter indexes?
- Maybe based on having run it, what's the ratio of duplicates you're expecting to find?  5%?  90%?
- How stable is the matching criteria requirement?

Example scenario:  If this was a run-on-command feature, it will be in my app indefinitely, it will get run weekly, with 10% or fewer records expected to be duplicates, with ability to change the DB how I'd like, if the duplicate matching criteria is firm (not fluctuating), and I wan to cut it from 90s to 5s, I'd create a dedicated `BirthYear` column (possibly a persisted computed column off of `BirthDate`), and an index on `LastName ASC, BirthYear ASC, FirstName ASC`.  If too many of those stipulations change, I might to a different direction entirely.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer @Matt, so I try it in db with 16 million, and it takes a bit more than 8 mins to run, I guess it will be run once a month,Yes, I have full permission to db, duplicates are less than 10%

Comment: Yea, forgot to mention, I should do paging, so records can be cuted

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, if you want paging in the same query, you're actually back to the analytic version.  And 8 minutes!  You definitely have factors affecting this outside the query itself.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, actually, after further consideration - maybe 8 minutes is OK if only once per month? :)  More seriously, have you tried running the Database Tuning Advisor (in Mgmt Studio -> "Tools" menu).  It shouldn't be used indiscriminately but it could give you some clues and before more back and forth on SO.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I will try to explain client that it is normal :) and to find some caching mechanism to do this once for a session...

Comment: Ah, if this is "clients" instead of support staff - I'm sure 8 minutes doesn't look good.  You almost certainly have options but, before getting into a dialog about them, I really think you should give DB Tuning Advisor a try just to save some back-and-forth on SO.  I'd really expect that index I gave you to have query times in 1s - 30s range.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this and see the difference on the execution plans, or benchmark the results on performance:

```
;WITH DupPersons AS
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(firstName, 1, 1), lastName, YEAR(birthDate)) Quant
    FROM Person
)

SELECT *
FROM DupPersons
WHERE Quant > 1
```

Of course, it would also help to know your table definition and the indexes you created. I think that maybe it can help to add a computed column with the year of birthdate and create an index on it, the same with the first letter of firstname.

Comment: doesn't compile, what I mean?

Comment: +1 for offering an approach using analytic fns. :)  This is one hit on the table instead of two, so has the potential to be more efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, it works longer than my query :( by the way, I need to cut first 20 records, how can I try this method in that case?

Comment: Unfortunately, as you saw, the "one table hit" potential doesn't automatically make it faster. I love analytics, and think devs should explore them more, but SQL Server's are hit or miss.

Comment: @Matt yeah, it could go both ways, but its worth the try ;)